# How to interface with the Linux tun driver

Tags: c, linux, tun

I'm having a hard time figuring this problem out - I am trying to write a program that will interact with the Linux tunnel driver. At a very basic level, I simply want to create an application that is able to transfer data over a network tunnel.  However, I am completely at a loss as to how to properly set up the tunnel driver in order to accomplish this.

I am developing on Ubuntu 9.04, and I have the tunnel driver kernel module loaded.

There exists the device `/dev/net/tun`, however there are no `/dev/tunX` devices. I am unable to create these devices using `ifconfig` - whenever I run `/sbin/ifconfig tun0 up`, for example, I get the following error:

> tun0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device.

If I attempt to look at the `/dev/net/tun` device, the following error is presented:

> cat: /dev/net/tun: File descriptor in bad state.

Attempting to open `/dev/tunX` via a small program, basically, a simple

```
tun_fd = open( "/dev/tun0", O_RDWR )
```

returns -1: the application is running as root and still cannot open this tunnel device. It is possible to open `/dev/net/tun`, however this does not appear to generate a new `/dev/tunX` device to use instead.

So, in summary - how does one go about writing an application that wishes to use the Linux tunnel driver?  Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks;
~Robert

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Read [`/usr/src/linux/Documentation/networking/tuntap.rst`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/tuntap.rst?id=HEAD).

You are supposed to `open` the `/dev/net/tun` device.  A subsequent `ioctl` on the open fd will create the `tun0` (or whatever you wish to name it) network interface.  Linux's network interfaces do not correspond to any `/dev/*` device.

Comment: @rmrobins;  what did you do to actually get this working?  I believe I have a very similar problem to your original question.  I have the /dev/net/tun device visible, but opening this does not produce a network interface.  I have been trying to use  the br_select.c and br_sigio.c examples.

Comment: As mentioned above, open /dev/net/tun.  Then, an ioctl will be used to create the actual interface itself.  The ioctl is called TUNSETIFF, and the argument is of type struct ifreq.  The flags of the ifreq struct should be set to IFF_TUN.  Once the ioctl has returned, the ifr_name field of the ifreq struct will be set with the name of the opened interface.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 33):

There are no `/dev/tunX` device files. Instead, you open the `/dev/net/tun` and configure it via `ioctl()` to "point" to `tun0`. To show the basic procedure, I will create the TUN interface using the command line tool `ip tun tap` and then show the C code to read from that TUN device. So to create the tun interface via commands line:

```
ip addr show # my eth0 inet address is 10.0.2.15/24 as Im running on a VirtualBox vm with Ubuntu 18.04 guest
sudo ip tuntap add mode tun dev tun0
sudo ip addr add 10.0.3.0/24 dev tun0  # give it an address (that does not conflict with existing IP)
sudo ip link set dev tun0 up  # bring the if up
ip route get 10.0.3.50  # check that packets to 10.0.3.x are going through tun0
# 10.0.3.50 dev tun0 src 10.0.3.0 uid 1000 
ping 10.0.3.50 # leave this running in another shell to be able to see the effect of the next example, nobody is responding to the ping
```

The `tun0` is created and all packets to destination IP address 10.0.3.x will be routed to `tun0`.

To read / write packets to this interface from an user space program you need to interact with the `/dev/net/tun` device file using `ioctl()`. Here is an example that will read the packets arriving at the `tun0` interface and print the size:

```
#include <fcntl.h>     /* O_RDWR */
#include <stdio.h>     /* perror(), printf(), fprintf() */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* exit(), malloc(), free() */
#include <string.h>    /* memset(), memcpy() */
#include <sys/ioctl.h> /* ioctl() */
#include <unistd.h>    /* read(), close() */

/* includes for struct ifreq, etc */
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int tun_open(char* devname)
{
    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd, err;

    if ((fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) == -1) {
        perror("open /dev/net/tun");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN;
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, devname, IFNAMSIZ); // devname = "tun0" or "tun1", etc

    /* ioctl will use ifr.if_name as the name of TUN
     * interface to open: "tun0", etc. */
    if ((err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void*)&ifr)) == -1) {
        perror("ioctl TUNSETIFF");
        close(fd);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* After the ioctl call the fd is "connected" to tun device specified
     * by devname ("tun0", "tun1", etc)*/

    return fd;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fd, nbytes;
    char buf[1600];

    fd = tun_open("tun0"); /* devname = ifr.if_name = "tun0" */
    printf("Device tun0 opened\n");
    while (1) {
        nbytes = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
        printf("Read %d bytes from tun0\n", nbytes);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you have the `ping 10.0.3.1` or `ping 10.0.3.40` running, you will see `Read 88 bytes from tun0` periodically.

You can also test using netcat UDP with `nc -u 10.0.3.3 2222` and typing text + Enter.

If nothing is being printed is most likely that the id address / ip range assigned to the tun0 is not reachable/routable/addressable. Make sure that the `ip route get 10.0.3.4` shows `10.0.3.4 dev tun0` indicating that the linux kernels knows that packets to 10.0.3.4 should be sent to the tun0 device.

To delete the `tun0` do

```
sudo ip link set dev tun0 down
sudo ip tuntap del mode tun dev tun0
```

Comment: this answer is missing the statement: `#include <unistd.h>` for the functions `read()` and `close()`.

Comment: If I run your C code, no packets are actually read in response to pinging the tun interface.

Comment: I just tried it and it works on Ubuntu 18.04 at least. @Peter make sure that the ip address / range that you assigned to the tun0 interface makes sense, and that is reachable/routable (the ip that I used in the example may conflict with your ip plan )

Answer (score 3):

I came across a nice intro tutorial about this

http://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/

It comes with a source tarball.

It was in the same set of Google results as this question.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

another implementation using api `fopen` `fclose` `fread` in `stdio.h` in c11, instead of api in `unistd.h`

```
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

FILE* tun_alloc(char *dev)
{
   struct ifreq ifr;
   FILE *fp;
   int err;

   // open in binary read+write mode
   if ((fp = fopen("/dev/net/tun", "r+b")) == 0)
   {
      perror("failed to open tun dev\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));

   /* Flags: IFF_TUN   - TUN device (no Ethernet headers)
    *        IFF_TAP   - TAP device
    *
    *        IFF_NO_PI - Do not provide packet information
    */
   ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN;
   if (*dev)
      strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);

   if ((err = ioctl(fileno(fp), TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr)) < 0)
   {
      fclose(fp);
      perror("failed to set mode!\n");
      exit(1);
   }
   strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);
   return fp;
}

int main(void)
{
   char dev_name[IFNAMSIZ] = "tun0";
   char recv_buff[80];
   FILE* fp = tun_alloc(dev_name);

   // turn off buffering
   setbuf(fp, NULL); 

   while (1)
   {
      printf("reading from TUN device: %s\n", dev_name);
      size_t n = fread(recv_buff, sizeof(recv_buff[0]), sizeof(recv_buff), fp);
      printf("read bytes: %li\n", n);
   }
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```