# How does /dev/net/tun works? Do I get back what I write?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

Suppose that I want to send and receive data through a `tun` device.

I found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35735842/6655884 where it opens `/dev/net/tun` as if it were a file and reads from it. However, what if I want to send a packet to it? If I simply `write` to it, then I'm gonna get the packet back when I `read` from it, or I migth get lucky and read after the packet was sent.

How it works? Does `/dev/net/tun` consumes what I write and not give it back when I read? Does it have knowledge of what is sent and received? I imagine it works like a file so whatever I write I get back when I read.

Comment: When yo write a packet, it goes to the destination.  If the destination is yourself then you get back what you write.

Comment: the linked answer is missing the statement: #include <unistd.h> for the functions read() and close()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How it works? Does /dev/net/tun consumes what I write and not
> give it back when I read?

Indeed.
You never get back what was written.

> I imagine it works like a file so whatever I write I get back when I read.

No, it works like a device node.
What is written, goes to a device
(in this case - virtual device).
What is read, is read from a (virtual)
device.
Think of /dev/tty: you don't read what
was written there. Instead, you read what
was typed on a keyboard, and what was
written can be seen on a screen.